# How To Create a Standalone Swift SDK

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to create a SDK to use without iOS or Xcode.

Let me explain. I would like to use Swift language to create a framework with which to develop front-end. In few words with this framework I would like create html pages for web and substitute HTML, CSS and javascript with swift. The idea get from what Apple does with iOS. If you look how is made a xib or storyboard you can see  xml file. I would like to do the same thing or take the idea and applicate for the web.

To do this I need to create an SDK that is not connected to iOS but that I can use in any IDE like VSCode or similar or also in a my own IDE created by me.

An other thing that could help you to understand what I mean is Javascript. In javascript there is a command `createElement` that let you to create an element, adding class, attribute and, yes, style. But create UI in this way, you understand well that is very hard. So, I Would like create a framework in iOS style, to create frontend in simpler and easier way.

I would like create create this framework (if it's possible) in Xcode and I don't want have any interference by iOS.

So, have you any suggests about how to start?

thank you

Comment: See https://swift.org/download/   Swift is well supported on Mac, Linux, and Windows. There is no requirement for iOS or Xcode. You can use whatever editor (or IDE) you like. Visual Studio Code has a Swift mode if you like that. https://nshipster.com/vscode/ While not exactly what you're discussing, see tools like https://vapor.codes for examples of server-side Swift generating web interfaces. You may also want to see Objective-J for inspiration (though it was based on ObjC). https://www.cappuccino.dev

Comment: Thank you for answer. I've seen the forum but, I'm sorry, I don't understand in which section I can start the discussion about my project. Is there a section for general purpose or which section you suggest to start my discussion?

Comment: I would recommend beginning questions in https://forums.swift.org/c/swift-users/15. For learning what exists in this space, I recommend https://forums.swift.org/c/server/43  For example, you might read posts like https://forums.swift.org/t/experience-of-using-vscode-as-a-swift-ide/50271

Comment: What you're describing is a project of a pretty massive scale and very technically complex, that would probably require you to become an expert in Javascript/CSS/HTML, as well as Swift, to achieve. Instead you could look at something like [Plot](https://github.com/JohnSundell/Plot), which is a framework that attempts something similar.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez thank you very much for the analyses about the project, but this doesn't answer to my question. I've seen Plot project and it is interesting. I can take some idea form my project, but I need to know how to create the framework. then to be an expert about HTML, CSS, Javascript and swift is not a problem

Comment: You're right, it doesn't answer your question, that's why it's a comment. I mentioned the scale and complexity of your question because that's the reason it's not suited for SO. This is not a code writing or designing service, you're expected to break down your problem down, do your research and attempt to solve them yourself first. "How to start?" is not a good question for this site.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez Forgive me if I gave you this impression, but you are wrong. I asked this question because I need guidance on how to set up a project in Xcode in order to make it a standalone framework. Unfortunately I have no knowledge and experience about it. I can't find anything on the internet that explains how to create a standalone framework. I find out how to create frameworks for iOS. but not standalone. According to the SO documentation this question is a "practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development". Because we developers create frameworks, even standalone

Answer (score 0):

XIB layout is constraint-based, which means you describe your view hierarchy and constraints, and autolayout system does the layout for you every time according to constraints you've provided. Technically, inside it converts constraints to a system of linear equations and solves it in run-time, thus calculating frames for every `UIView`. And .xib file is just an XML with all the views, their properties and constraints. (that's a bit simplified, but you've got the idea)

HTML layout is totally different: HTML is a declarative way to describe elements on a page, i.e you describe every element with tags, and every tag (or its parent, or CSS file) already contains all necessary information about its positioning and appearance, so browser just parses and renders a page accordingly.

Theoretically, you could've reinvented a web browser: write your HTML parser, then write UI to somehow render it, and add feature to alter HTML tags by moving the page elements with mouse. But that would've taken a lot of time and effort :)

There are many website constructors on WWW, which allow you to build simple sites only with drag-and-drop (no coding needed). Also, you can inspect element in your browser, and then change some attributes of some element right in the debug window, and see changes in realtime.

P.S Im not a web/frontend developer, but I suppose that IDE's popular among frontenders already have some features or plugins that allow them to render HTML/CSS code and see changes in realtime, just like browser's debug menu.

Comment: Thank you for answer. But it's not correct. because in source code of Xib or Storyboard you find a declaration of any components with its attribute. You said that you are not web/frontend developer. In fact, if you were a frontend developer you would also know that the thing i would like to do is possible to do it with javascript. What I would like to do is the same thing, in a much easier and simpler way and in swift, iOS style. but to do that I need to create a standalone framework to be able to use it without the influence of iOS, since I would like to create it (if possible) in Xcode.